# Check if Get-NetTCPConnection Object Exists

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-10

I have an if statement that I am trying to figure out, basically it is

```
If(Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5900 -State Established) {}
```

The end goal is that if a connection exists on that port with the established state, do something.
The issue I am running into is figuring out how to check to see if any connections with those parameters exist at all, since if none exist I get the "No Matching MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found by CIM" error, it does not affect the execution of the script but it's an ugly error that I am trying to lint.

I have tried:

```
If($Null -ne (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5900 -State Established)){}
If(-Not [String]IsNullorEmpty::((Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5900 -State Established))){}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the parameter **ErrorAction** like this:

`If(Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5900 -State Established -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {Write-host "Established!"}`

Comment: That actually worked perfectly, the script runs as it should and no errors on receive-job, thank you!

Comment: I think that actually exist a best approach, but this is a simple way to solve the output